# How to insert multiple data templates into main date template

Tags: wpf, mef, datatemplate

I am using AvalonDock and MEF plugin architecture, 
Each plugin returns a data template to host, host get the data template, insert to main data template.

Following are user controls that are converted to DataTemplates

MainMethodView: including a tab,

PluginA's MethodView: need to be inserted to MainMethodView's tab item 1.

PluginB's MethodView: need to be inserted to MainMethodView's tab item 2.

.....

Thanks.

Code: InitializePlugins() i have only could shows one plugin's datatemplate. and GetMethodViewTemplate() gives me error: Content of a ContentControl must be a single element.

reference: [Link1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d4cce58a-4dca-450a-81c6-f5eec9279d3b/can-you-combine-2-datatemplates-into-one?forum=wpf)

```
public void InitializePlugins(){
var templateSelector = new PanesTemplateSelector();
    templateSelector.MethodViewTemplate = pluginService.Plugins[0].MethodViewTemplate;
    _dockingManger.LayoutItemTemplateSelector = templateSelector;   
}
private static DataTemplate GetMethodViewTemplate(PluginService pluginService) {
    FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(MethodView));
    foreach (var plugin in pluginService.Plugins) {
        FrameworkElementFactory fef = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentControl));
        fef.SetValue(ContentControl.ContentTemplateProperty, plugin.MethodViewTemplate);
        factory.AppendChild(fef);
    }
    DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();
    dt.VisualTree = factory;
    return dt;
}
```

Another problem is databinding, MainMethodViewModel has PluginMethodViewModels from plugins, How it could be binded to MainMethodView.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I found. Share everyone.
Note: View1 and View2 are usercontrol, binding setting is in xaml file.

```
  public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateTemplate4();
    }

    private void CreateTemplate4() {
        var method = new MethodViewModel();
        FrameworkElementFactory fefWrapper = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TabControl));

        foreach (var fred in method.Freds) {
            DataTemplate dt1 = fred.Template;
            FrameworkElementFactory fefTop = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentControl));
            fefTop.SetValue(ContentControl.ContentTemplateProperty, dt1);
            fefTop.SetValue(ContentControl.ContentProperty, fred);
            fefWrapper.AppendChild(fefTop);
        }
        DataTemplate dtWrapper = new DataTemplate(typeof(MethodViewModel));
        dtWrapper.VisualTree = fefWrapper;

        this.DataContext = method;
        this.cc.ContentTemplate = dtWrapper;

    }
class MethodViewModel {
    public ObservableCollection<Fred> Freds { get; set; }
    public MethodViewModel() {
        Freds = new ObservableCollection<Fred>();

        Freds.Add(new Fred1(1));
        Freds.Add(new Fred2(2));


    }
}

public class Fred {
    public int X { get;  set; }
    public int y { get;  set; }
    public Fred(int x) {
        this.X = x;
        this.y = x + 1;
    }
    public DataTemplate Template { get;  set; }
}
public class Fred1 : Fred {
    public Fred1(int x) : base(x) {
        FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(View1));
        DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();
        dt.VisualTree = factory;
        this.Template = dt;
    }
}
public class Fred2 : Fred {
     public Fred2(int x) : base(x) {
        FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(View2));
        DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();
        dt.VisualTree = factory;
        this.Template = dt;
    }
}
```